# auto resume suspended messages in Biztalk

Tags: biztalk

One of our Biztalk customers asks us automatically resend failed and suspended messages every 5 hours.
And problem is that developed orchestrations intensively uses Suspend shape so as far as I understand 
messages became suspended immediately without standard Biztalk retrial.

I'm going to write simple app that will resume suspended messages  via WMI Biztalk object .
Is this a good approach?

Does anybody has such application or did you find another resolution for this problem ?

Comment: Hi, If you "just" resume the suspended instance, processing will carry on from where it left off. Is this the desired behaviour? Or would you rather start processing from a point before the suspension?

Comment: You would need some kind of loop in the orchestration to allow processing to be retried in case of failure.

Comment: TJAmas, yes there is a loop in orchestrations, but problem is that [b]Suspend[/b] shape is used , and as far as I know it's suspending message immediately so loop doesn't make sense in this case. I was thinking to replace it with Throw shape, this will fail message and put it into  Biztalk port retrial. But building auto-resuming service could be also alternative.So I'm not sure what would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the suspend shape in the Orchestration with a delay shape configured to 5 hours.
Another options is to set the retry interval to 300 minutes and multiple retries on the send port.